# How are monster’s skills calculated?

Tags: dnd-4e, skills

For example, I’m looking at the Goblin Hex Hurler found in the Monster Vault. Its skills are Stealth +10, Thievery +10. The Monster Vault states:

> The skills section of a monster’s statistics block includes only trained skills or skills for which the monster has an unusual modifier.

Assuming the monster is trained in the skills (+5) and with an adjusted Dexterity modifier of +3, I’d expect the values to be +8, not +10. I thought this may be a racial bonus for Goblins, but the Goblin Sniper, Goblin Beast Rider, and Goblin Cutthroat all have only +8 to these same skills. Where is the remaining +2 coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The other goblins are missing their racial bonus.

According to *Monster Manual* p.278, the goblin has +2 racial bonus to +2 Stealth and Thievery. It's correctly reflected in all of the goblin statblocks in that book.

The *Monster Vault* statblock for the Hex Hurler correctly includes the goblin's **+2 racial bonus** to Stealth and Thievery. The Goblin Sniper, Goblin Beast Rider, and Goblin Cutthroat which are missing their +2 racial bonus.

Why? The best I can surmise is as follows.

The Sniper, Cutthroat, and Hex Hurler originally appeared in *Dungeon* #180 (Jul 2010), which pre-dates *Monster Vault* (Nov 2010) by a few months. Of these, the Goblin Hex Hurler is fundamentally the same as the Goblin Hexer from the *Monster Manual*, with some tweaks. The reason why the Hex Hurler has Stealth +10, Thievery +10 is certainly that **it's based on the Hexer**, which also had +10.

*Dungeon* #180 also had the Goblin Cutter, based on the Goblin Cutter from the *Monster Manual*, except for slight numerical tweaks. Notably, its Stealth and Thievery skills are increased from +5 (presumably +3 Dex, +2 racial, no training) to +8 (perhaps +3 Dex +5 training, forgetting the racial bonus in error, since it's not listed in the main Goblin entry in the *MM*). Then again, it may also be that the author arbitrarily increased it from +5 to +8 for game balance.

It also had the Goblin Warrior, who retained their +10 bonuses to the two skills from the *MM*. My hypothesis is that the Cutter was changed because the author mistakenly assumed the +5 was an error (+5 training, no Dex), but they left the +10 because that was clearly good enough.

*Dungeon* #180's Goblin Cutthroat also had +8. It's bizarre to see its statblock right next to the Goblin Warrior, because both of them are level 1 skirmishers with the same Dex modifier, so you'd think someone would have noticed. The Beast Rider seems to be new to *Monster Vault*, and its skills are no doubt copied from another of the goblins with +8.